# Stylesheet: SchemaLocation attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, schema

In my research, once we have the XML Schema Instance namespace available we can use the schemaLocation attribute.

In terms of their position in an XML tag, does the namespace always come first before the schema location?

This is my stylesheet code.

```
CarriageDelivery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:SchemaLocation="Carriage_Delivery.xsd"
```

and I'm trying to switch the position of `xmlns:xsi` attribute and `xsi:SchemaLocation` like this..

```
CarriageDelivery xsi:SchemaLocation="Carriage_Delivery.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

but in my generated output, nothing happened.

```
CarriageDelivery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:SchemaLocation="Carriage_Delivery.xsd"
```

I'm hoping I can get an explanation as to why it always appears last.

Comment: My guess is that the library you are using is implemented with said order, there should be no semantic difference in the order of both declarations.

Comment: The order makes no difference. I believe most processors will put namespaces before attributes when serializing the output, simply because it's convenient for them to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) says that the order of attributes on a given element is not significant. So 
it should not matter to any downstream application whether `xmlns:xsi` appears before `xsi:SchemaLocation`, or vice versa. For that reason, most programs that output XML (including XSLT processors, in general) don't give you any control or guarantee about what order they will output attributes in.

Can you explain why you want to specify the order? It shouldn't matter, except for human aesthetics...

Comment: And in the limited cases where it does matter (e.g. calculating a digital signature, where you need byte-for-byte equivalence) there are [defined standards for how to put XML in a canonical form](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n).